# Why, Lazy purely functional stack in F# is slower than non lazy stack?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I have compared lazy stack and non lazy stack implementation from: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures#Lazy_Data_Structures

In this article it says, append function is O(1) for lazy and O(n) for non lazy. However running below program shows that lazy stack is twice as slower from non lazy variant. What could be the cause of this ?

```
type lazyStack<'a> = 
    | Node of // return an integer exit code
              Lazy<'a * 'a lazyStack>
    | EmptyStack

module LazyStack = 
    let (|Consx|Nil|) = 
        function 
        | Node(item) -> 
            let hd, tl = item.Force()
            Consx(hd, tl)
        | EmptyStack -> 
            Nil

    let hd = 
        function 
        | Consx(hd, tl) -> hd
        | Nil -> failwith "empty"

    let tl = 
        function 
        | Consx(hd, tl) -> tl
        | Nil -> failwith "empty"

    let cons (hd, tl) = Node(lazy (hd, tl))
    let empty = EmptyStack

    let rec append x y = 
        match x with
        | Consx(hd, tl) -> 
            Node(lazy (hd, append tl y))
        | Nil -> 
            y

    let rec iter f = 
        function 
        | Consx(hd, tl) -> 
            f (hd)
            iter f tl
        | Nil -> ()

    let doDummyWork i = i + 1
    let x = cons (1, cons (2, cons (3, cons (4, EmptyStack))))
    let y = cons (5, cons (6, cons (7, EmptyStack)))

    let public dowork() = 
        let z = append x y
        let z = append z y
        ()

        hd z |> ignore

module Stack = 
    type stack<'a> = 
        | EmptyStack
        | StackNode of 'a * 'a stack

    let hd = 
        function 
        | EmptyStack -> failwith "Empty stack"
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> hd

    let tl = 
        function 
        | EmptyStack -> failwith "Emtpy stack"
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> tl

    let cons hd tl = StackNode(hd, tl)
    let empty = EmptyStack

    let rec update index value s = 
        match index, s with
        | index, EmptyStack -> failwith "Index out of range"
        | 0, StackNode(hd, tl) -> StackNode(value, tl)
        | n, StackNode(hd, tl) -> StackNode(hd, update (index - 1) value tl)

    let rec append x y = 
        match x with
        | EmptyStack -> 
            y
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> 
            StackNode(hd, append tl y)

    let rec map f = 
        function 
        | EmptyStack -> EmptyStack
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> StackNode(f hd, map f tl)

    let rec rev s = 
        let rec loop acc = 
            function 
            | EmptyStack -> acc
            | StackNode(hd, tl) -> loop (StackNode(hd, acc)) tl
        loop EmptyStack s

    let rec contains x = 
        function 
        | EmptyStack -> false
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> hd = x || contains x tl

    let rec fold f seed = 
        function 
        | EmptyStack -> seed
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> fold f (f seed hd) tl

    let rec iter f = 
        function 
        | StackNode(hd, tl) -> 
            f (hd)
            iter f tl
        | EmptyStack -> ()

    let doDummyWork i = i + 1
    let x = StackNode(1, StackNode(2, StackNode(3, StackNode(4, EmptyStack))))
    let y = StackNode(5, StackNode(6, StackNode(7, EmptyStack)))

    let public dowork() = 
        let z = append x y
        let z = append z y

        hd z |> ignore


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    let n = 1000000
    for i = 0 to n do
        Stack.dowork()
    printfn "%A" sw.Elapsed
    sw.Restart()
    for i = 0 to n do
        LazyStack.dowork()
    printfn "%A" sw.Elapsed
    0
```

Comment: What happens if you use (much) bigger stacks?

Comment: Yes bigger stacks, lazy version is far better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Big-O is how the runtime grows as your input size gets bigger.  It's quite common for an `O(1)` function to have a larger overhead than an `O(n)` function, and therefore be slower for very small values of `n`.  Since that overhead is relatively constant, though, at some point it will end up being faster.  Consider this graph from [here](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/asymptotic-complexity.html):

[image: O(1) and O(n) algorithm]

The `O(1)` solution is fixed at an overhead of 29, whereas the `O(n)` solution initially starts much lower than that, but grows linearly.  It's only when `n > 52` that the `O(1)` solution becomes more efficient.

Try appending two very large stacks and you will see a significant difference.

Comment: you are right increasing the stack size to 1000s make lazy version far more efficient.